# passing mobx-react-form object as a prop

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to pass `mobx-react-form` object as a prop to a function component I created. the problem is when I call my component like that 

`<NameEditor form={ newFolderForm }/>`

I do get the form argument inside `NameEditor` component but it doesn't let me 'edit' the field .. its like the field isn't editable,
but when I call the component like that 

`{ NameEditor({ form: newFolderForm }) }`

it works perfectly fine, what am I missing ? shouldn't the both ways be the same thing in function components ?

edit: here is how I fetch the form

```
const NameEditor = ({ form }) => (
 <form onSubmit={ form.onSubmit }>
  <input { ...form.$('name').bind() }/>
  <p>{ form.$('name').error }</p>
  <button>Save</button>
 </form>
)
```

thanks

Comment: basically in function components they are the same, try to console.log the form argument in both ways see the different

Comment: @Danny, I tried logging the `{ ...form.$('name').bind() }` I get exactly the same object.

Comment: sounds strange try showing more from you'r code .. like how do you fetch the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are using `observer()` on you're function component, from the code you showed there I think you missed this part.

```
const NameEditor = observer(({ form }) => (
 <form onSubmit={ form.onSubmit }>
  <input { ...form.$('name').bind() }/>
  <p>{ form.$('name').error }</p>
  <button>Save</button>
 </form>
))
```

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html
read how it works with Stateless function components